# this.id is undefined in onchange event after page reload

Tags: javascript, events, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a following problem:

I have one HTML element (dropdown), with `onchange` event, that accepts two parameters (`id` and `value`). Everything is working fine. Except in one case. When I do page reload, this `onchange` event will be triggered, but `id` and `value` parameters will be undefined. Without this two parameters, this function will not do anything.

I am using CakePHP, so I am doing it like this:

```
'size' => [
    'label'   => 'Test label',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'options' => [
        "1x1"         => 'Single',
        "2x1"         => 'Double'
    ],
    'help'    => 'Help text',
    'onchange' => 'change_viewport(this.id, this.value)'
]
```

and a JS function that starts like this:

```
function change_viewport(id, value) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(value);
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this, so that I get correct id and value?

I know that I could solve this by calling `setTimeout()' and call function that will get this parameters, but the problem is, that I can have multiple sections with this size element, and I would not know which one is correct.

Thank you

**Edit 1: HTML of dropdown element**

This is what CakePHP outputs for above definition for size

```
<select name="data[PromotionActionInjectionBanner][0][size]" onchange="change_viewport(this.id, this.value)" class="PromotionActionInjectionBanner_size chzn-chosen span8 chzn-done" data-placeholder="Select an option" repeatit=" PromotionActionInjectionBanner_size PromotionActionInjectionBanner size 0 secondary" markedoptions="" id="PromotionActionInjectionBanner0Size" idtemplate="PromotionActionInjectionBanner0Size" nametemplate="data%5BPromotionActionInjectionBanner%5D%5B0%5D%5Bsize%5D" style="display: none;">
<option value="1x1" selected="selected">Single</option>
<option value="2x1">Double</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet of your HTML code where the `onchange` event is defined?

Comment: @SparkFountain I have added html of dropdown to my question.

Comment: *Suggestion:* change the function call to `change_viewport(this)` then in the function call, change to `change_viewport(e)` _(where 'e' is for 'element')_. Then test that in the function with (assuming jQuery) `console.log($(e).attr('id'))` _(although it might be "prop" not "attr", I never remember which)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  as following :

```
'size' => [
    'label'   => 'Test label',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'options' => [
        "1x1"         => 'Single',
        "2x1"         => 'Double'
    ],
    'help'    => 'Help text',
    'onchange' => 'change_viewport(this)'
]
```

And change JS function as  :

```
function change_viewport(e) {
    console.log(e.id);
    console.log(e.value);
}
```

It should work fine . I have tested the following code snippet, you can run it online to check  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery Online</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("em").addClass("selected");
   $("#myid").addClass("highlight");
});

function clicks(e){
    alert(e.id);alert(e.value);

}
</script>
<style>
.selected { 
    color:red; 
}
.highlight { 
    background:yellow; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<em title="Bold and Brave">This is first paragraph.</em>
<p id="myid">This is second paragraph.</p>
<select  id ="id_name " onchange="clicks(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```